# Wireguard duplicate IP if cert on multiple devices

Tags: wireguard

We've been using Wireguard with great success, but recently found if a user uses a cert(client is the term used in the GUI) on multiple devices they both get the same IP resulting in packet loss/network instability.

We are looking for ways to identify or even better prevent this from happening. Any recommendations?

We don't intend for end users to reuse a cert/client, but it happens so looking for help to prevent this and/or identify if it is happening.